# C# Blocking collection processing an item twice

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, c#-4.0

Below is a sample mimic of the actual production enviornment. In some scenarios, in the below example an item retrieved from the blocking collection is processed twice by different threads.

Does anyone know the cause of this issue? Even with the below code, it's very difficult to simulate the issue, the issue only occurs in the production environment.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TestBlockingCollection obj1 = new TestBlockingCollection();

        obj1.InvokeThread();

        for(int i=0; i<=10; i++)
        {
            obj1.AddToLiveDataQueue($"Item-{i}");
        }
    }
}
class TestBlockingCollection
{
    BlockingCollection<string>Quueue { get; set; }
    public void AddToLiveDataQueue(string msg)
    {
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"[{System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}] Adding to live data queue");
            Quueue.TryAdd(msg);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
    public void InvokeThread()
    {
        Quueue = new BlockingCollection<string>();
        ThreadStart threadObj = new ThreadStart(ConsumerThread);
        Thread thread = new Thread(threadObj);
        thread.Start();
    }
    private void ConsumerThread()
    {
        foreach (string item in Quueue.GetConsumingEnumerable())
        {
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"[{System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}] Started processing {item}");
                Thread.Sleep(10000); // does some operation
                Console.WriteLine($"[{System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}] Finished processing {item}");

            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "is processed twice by different threads". In your sample code there is only one thread doing processing.

Comment: Is it possible that you call the `InvokeThread` method twice in the production environment?

Comment: No chance. its only called once, when the exe starts.

Comment: I am a bit nervous that the `BlockingCollection` is instantiated inside the `InvokeThread` method. I would prefer it to be declared `readonly`, and instantiated in the constructor. I don't think that this will solve your problem though. Probably something else is going on, in some other part of the program.

Comment: I would really ask you to post the production code that actually has the issue rather than the demo code that doesn't. Can you do that please?

Answer (score -1):

Im not 100% on this as I can't see any implementation details for your BlockingCollection, but my hunch is the following code might be the culprit:

```
foreach (string item in Quueue.GetConsumingEnumerable())
```

You might be getting the same items copied into multiple 'Enumerable' objects and the calling thread processes the entire list.

It might be worth trying something along these lines:

```
string item;
while ((item = Quueue.GetNext()) != null)
{
  try
  {
    Console.WriteLine($"[{System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}] Started processing {item}");
    Thread.Sleep(10000); // does some operation
    Console.WriteLine($"[{System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}] Finished processing {item}");

  }
  catch(Exception e)
  {
    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
  }
}
```

Where GetNext() explicitly removes one and only one item off the BlockingCollection each time its called.